# Join SQL query results inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to join result sets inside a stored procedure, I tried this query but it is incorrect.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table1 WHERE Field4='val1') A
INNER JOIN 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Field1, Field3 FROM Table1 WHERE Field4='val2') b
ON A.Field1 = B. Fileld1
```

How to join resulting tables inside a stored procedure?

Comment: "joins" work the same way *inside* of a stored procedure as they do with with pure T-SQL.  Your join is simply wrong.  Q: What exactly is it you want to do???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

you don't have to use SELECT * FROM twice..

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table1 WHERE Field4='val1') A
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Field1, Field3 FROM Table1 WHERE Field4='val2') b
ON A.Field1 = B. Fileld1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing some this like this (Just for an example):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 A 
INNER JOIN 
SELECT * FROM Table2 B 
ON A.FIELD1 = B.FIELD2
```

Which is wrong. Because you don't need to write `SELECT * FROM` twice. Correct one is:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 A 
INNER JOIN 
Table2 B 
ON A.FIELD1 = B.FIELD2
```

So your query should be(Including Create procedure):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testJoining 
AS 
    SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT FIELD1, Field2 FROM Table1 WHERE Field4='VAL1') A
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT FIELD1, Field3 FROM Table1 WHERE Field4='VAL2') B
    ON A.FIELD1 = B.FIELD1
GO
```

[See this fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aab88/7)
Other way to select data from the same table is:

```
SELECT A.Field1,A.Field2,B.Field3 FROM Table1 A 
INNER JOIN 
Table1 B 
ON A.FIELD1 = B.FIELD1
WHERE A.Field4='VAL1'
AND B.Field4='VAL2'
```

[See this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aab88/16)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would help

```
With cte_sample AS ( SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table1 
WHERE Field4='val1' )
SELECT Field1, Field3 FROM Table1 AS a
INNER JOIN cte_sample ON a.Field1 = cte_sample.Field1 AND
WHERE a.Field4='val2'
```